# How to change activity when click drawer menu item?

Tags: android

I have a drawer menu which by Android Studio.

My menu's code:

```
        //Menü kodları//
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_fbdown) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_instadown) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_twitdown) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_privacy) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_contact) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

I want to make clicktable this menu. I tired this code:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(FBDownActivity.this, FBDownActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_fbdown) {
        Intent i = new Intent(FBDownActivity.this, FBDownActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_instadown) {
        Intent i = new Intent(FBDownActivity.this, FBDownActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_twitdown) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_privacy) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_contact) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

But it's didn't work. Still can't click to item.
What Can I do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: It did work. It started the same activity

Comment: Code looks correct. It should work. Try starting a different activity to notice change evidently.

Comment: If you have time, I give you Team Viewer ID and connect me and look to project? If you have time.

Comment: It's ok. I forget to change setContentView(R.layout.activity_insta_down); in new activity :D That's why I see not changing activity :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start the same activity as you are. Change the code bellow:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_fbdown) {
        Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivty.this, ActivityToOpen.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_instadown) {
        Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivty.this, ActivityToOpen.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_twitdown) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_privacy) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_contact) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I know this it's was just example bro I changed but still not going to new activity.